# How can I open a menu using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

We have a shortcut menu that if the user presses the `.` key, a shortcut menu opens.
How can I mimic the user's behavior? 
From the docs, the `t.keyPress` works only on inputs and cannot be initiated out side it

Comment: shouldn't it be await t.pressKey('.') ? also, were you able to try in different browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an input element for [`t.keyPress`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/presskey.html) to work.

**Edit:**

Here is a simple test using `t.pressKey('.')`:

```js
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture`Press key`
  .page`./index.html`;

test('Press dot', async t => {
    await t        
        .pressKey('.')
        .expect(Selector('p').textContent).eql('Dot is pressed');
});
```

index.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <p id='paragraph'>Press key</p>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
                if (event.key === '.')
                    document.getElementById('paragraph').textContent = 'Dot is pressed';
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So it doesn’t work when I try to await t.keyPress(‘.’)

Comment: I updated the answer with a working test. Could you share more details about your scenario? A simple example illustrating the issue would be appreciated.